# Accessing pagination elements in zend framework2

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

I am using the pagination using zend framework2 and i am getting the array as below

```
 Zend\Paginator\Paginator Object
(
[cacheEnabled:protected] => 1
[adapter:protected] => Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter Object
    (
        [array:protected] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 123
                [AccountId] => 1
                [Name] => abc abc
                [AccountName] => a1
            )

        [count:protected] => 4
    )

[currentItemCount:protected] => 
[currentItems:protected] => 
[currentPageNumber:protected] => 1
[filter:protected] => 
[itemCountPerPage:protected] => 25
[pageCount:protected] => 1
[pageRange:protected] => 10
[pages:protected] => 
[view:protected] => 
)
```

But my question is how can i access the Id,AccountId,Name,AccountName individual without using the foreach loop ?

Comment: The zend paginator was designed to be looped, you can try get the adaptor and then convert it to array to be access by index. What are you trying to do?

Comment: +1 to @ClaudioPinto's "The zend paginator was designed to be looped". I would add that at some point you pass the raw query/array when creating the Paginator. Why not just use that raw data rather than introduce the overhead of a new paginator class?

Comment: @Claudio Pinto  I am using the foreach loop to access this. But it is giving me the all the indexing but i want specific.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the adapter implement [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) class, which allows you to access a specific index. I'm not 100% sure, we stopped using zend paginator long time ago. What are you trying to achieve? There might be another way.

Comment: @Claudio Pinto  I have just count the array the array and showing the desired output. But i have already used ArrayIterator in zend paginator.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in documentation, there is public function [getItem](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-paginator/blob/master/src/Paginator.php#L501)

`public function getItem($itemNumber, $pageNumber = null)`

Using it is not that simple as accessing by index of array, but keep in mind that internal data in adapter is usually lazy loaded.

So you'd better to write some wrapper class with [ArrayAcccess](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayaccess.php) implemented which relies on getItem in case you want to access elements by index.